# Ruby on rails and mysql 2 on mac

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, macos, rubygems

I work in macosx v10.6.8 and i have :
- ruby v 1.9.3p385
- rails v 3.2.12
- gem 1.8.25
- mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.10, for osx10.6 (i386) using  EditLine wrapper

Whene in try gem builde install, i see this message error :
/Users/admin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bin/gem:4: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/mysql/bin in PATH, mode 040777
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (RuntimeError)
    Unknown command builde

I tape chmod -R 777 but same error.

And when i try gem install mysql2, i see this message error :
/Users/admin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bin/gem:4: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/mysql/bin in PATH, mode 040777
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied - /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/.gitignore

I clean that whith chmod -R 777 but again same error !!!

I need a help, tnx every body

Answer (score 0):

Well the error is telling you that the 777 permission is a problem, it shouldn't be world writeable. I assume you're using this exclusively for local testing, try it with a 755 or 775 permission.